# Remove comma when between quotes from batch or PoSh

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a CSV file with a content like:

```
A,B,C
D,"E,F",G
H,I,"J,K,L"
```

I need to remove the commas when between quotes (also remove the quotes, but that is not so important):

```
A,B,C
D,EF,G
H,I,JKL
```

I looked at PoSh [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) operator but I can't get it to capture multiple group values:

```
 PS >"D,`"E,F`",G" -replace "`"((?:[^,`"]+)\,?)+`"", '$1'
 D,F,G
```

as you can see when the group is repeated, only the last value captured is preserved. Is there a way to do the transformation I want?

https://regex101.com/r/ON1rgp/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may define a callback to pass to the `Regex::Replace` method where you may just grab the part between quotes and remove all `,` there:

```
$callback = {  param($match) $match.Groups[1].Value.Replace(',','') }
$s =  "D,`"E,F`",G"
$rex = [regex]'"([^"]*)"'
$rex.Replace($s, $callback)
```

[image]

The regex is `"([^"]*)"` that matches `"`, then captures into Group 1 (i.e. the `$match.Groups[1].Value`) any zero or more chars other than `"` and then matches `"`. It will need enhancing in case you have escaped quotes, but the approach will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to using regex:

```
Import-Csv your.csv | Foreach-Object { 
    $_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { $_.Value = $_.Value -replace ',' }
    $_
 } | Export-csv your-new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

We use `Import-CSV` to import the data as a PowerShell object. We then iterate through the value of each property of each row of the CSV to replace the ',' character with nothing. Then we export it to a new CSV.